# macos, terminal emacs overwrite ui emacs' buffer history (and probably other things)

Tags: spacemacs, dired, helm, osx

I am a `macos` & `spacemacs` user and installed my emacs through `https://emacsformacosx.com/`. For UI based emacs I just click on the emacs icon. For terminal I run this command: `alias emacs='$(/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@" -nw)'`.

I want to run emacs both in the terminal and by UI. However, It seems to be every time I run both, one emacs overwrite the other's buffer history. Is there some configuration I should tweak to allow them sharing the history?

By buffer history I mean the `SPACE-b-b` command in `spacemacs` as shown below:

[image]